# Why can I take the address of a string literal, but not of an integer literal?

Tags: c++

I just stumbled over the following line of code

```
cout << &"Blahh" << endl;
```

The compiler doesn't give an error and on the console the address is displayed. It works all correctly without any problem. If I replace "Blahh" with an int, so

```
cout << &10 << endl;
```

the code won't compile. For short: a string literal works but an integer literal not.

What is the reason why `cout << &"Blahh" << endl;` works and `cout << &10 << endl;` not?

Comment: Short answer: `10` is an rvalue, `"Blahh"` is an lvalue.

Comment: Another statement of "code won't compile" with no mention of the compiler or the error message.  Will people never learn?

Comment: @abelenky: do you mean individuals, or the entire human race genetically evolving to know from birth that this is annoying?

Comment: I see no references in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `"Blahh"` has an address in memory (it's an l-value). `10` doesn't (it's an r-value).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29

Comment: "*`10` will go straight into a register*" has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: The question though is *why* is `"Blahh"` an lvalue if `10` isn’t. This answer clarifies terminology but doesn’t explain.

Comment: Well, feel free to write a better answer. How much detail can I go into without it "having nothing to do with C++"?

Comment: By citing the C++ standard and explaining why one works and the other doesn't. The underlying implementation details are certainly irrelevant -- this is about _semantics_.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `"Blahh"` is an lvalue because it would be much less useful if it were an rvalue. If it were an array-of-char rvalue, you couldn't do anything at all with it. If it were a pointer-to-char rvalue, you couldn't take its size with `sizeof`. The fact that you can take its address is a result of it being an lvalue, not a reason for it.

Comment: `"Blahh"` is an lvalue because it has type `char[6]`, and C/C++ don't have rvalues with array types.  If C style arrays were first class types, then it would probably be an rvalue as well, but since they aren't...

Comment: @James: That's wrong, there are indeed rvalue arrays: `alias<int[]>{ 1, 2, 3 };` with `template<class T> using alias = T;`.

Answer (score 4):

A string literal such as `"Blahh"` is of type `const char[6]` and as such has memory allocated to it in the address space. The integer literal constant `10` does NOT have a specific memory location assigned to it and as such cannot have its address taken (as an aside, imagine if you could change the value of the constant `10` in your program).

Comment: As an aside, imagine if you could change the value of `"Blahh"` in your program.