# Is it possible to pass a pointer to a literal?

Tags: c++, pointers, methods, syntax, literals

Imagine we have:

```
void foo(int *num){}
```

And we know we are always passing 5 as a parameter, one could then do:

```
int var = 5;
foo(&var);
```

Is there any syntax to avoid the explicit variable declaration?

In essence something like:

```
foo(&(5));
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Just write `void foo(int const& num)`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116513/why-can-i-take-the-address-of-a-string-literal-but-not-of-an-integer-literal.  Trying to find a better dupe target

Comment: What would the address of a literal mean? And worse, what would happen if you tried to modify the value stored there?

Comment: I did not write the function and it's a driver function so i do not get to write it how I want

Comment: If the pointer is non-`const` there is a good chance that the driver intends to write to the pointed-to object.

Comment: In this case not really. it will copy the data from the pointer into a buffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only take the address of an [lvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category). A literal is a prvalue, not an lvalue, so you cannot take the address of a literal. Conceptually, there is no need for a literal such as `5` to have any storage and without some form of storage there is no address to be had.

Though, you could pass it to a `const int &`.

```
void foo(const int &) {}

int main()
{
    foo(5);
}
```

Comment: *Though, you could pass it to a const int &* Why would you though?  `void foo(int)` does the same thing

Comment: I did not write the function declaration, and it's a driver function, so i cannot modify it whatsoever.

Comment: Is tehre nothing like a lambda variable?

Comment: @NathanOliver I can't think of a scenario where you would want to do this instead of taking by value. It wasn't clear to me at the time of writing what OP was trying to do, but I feel like pass by `const` reference was the closest thing to the code that was originally supplied while still being legal c++.